# How do I return words from strings using regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex

I have some data which looks like:

```
{i:0;s:2:"69";i:1;s:2:"70";i:2;s:2:"71";i:3;s:2:"72";i:4;s:2:"73";i:5;s:2:"74";i:6;s:2:"75";i:7;s:2:"76";i:8;s:2:"77";}
```

I need to remove all items within quotation marks, e.g. `69,70,..,77`.

I understand I should use the `preg_split` function.

I'm looking for help regarding the regular expression I need to pass to `preg_split` in order to return the required data.

**Edit**

Sorry, my initial question wasn't clear. I want to gather all values between speech marks and have them returned in an array (i'm not interested in keeping the rest of the data - all I require are the values within speech marks)

**Edit 2**
The data is a serialized object, I didn't include the full object in order to save space.

Comment: This looks like data produced by the [serialize function](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). Isn't it easier to use this function to convert it to an array, edit this, and convert it back?

Comment: Give us an example of result.

Comment: I agree with Max... you will have to add `a:NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS` to the beginning of the string though...

Comment: I edited my answer to search only the strings between quotes. (But thats really a strange approach to get these values.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without regexp:

```
$v = 'a:9:{i:0;s:2:"69";i:1;s:2:"70";i:2;s:2:"71";i:3;s:2:"72";i:4;s:2:"73";i:5;s:2:"74";i:6;s:2:"75";i:7;s:2:"76";i:8;s:2:"77";}';
$v = unserialize($v);
print_r($v);
$v = array_combine(array_keys($v), array_fill(0, count($v), ''));
echo serialize($v);
```

but this looks, how max mentioned, like a (part of a) serialized object.
you should check if you are able to work with the complete syntax of it...

**update**

well, if you only want the values of this serialized array, it gets even easier:

```
$v = 'a:9:{i:0;s:2:"69";i:1;s:2:"70";i:2;s:2:"71";i:3;s:2:"72";i:4;s:2:"73";i:5;s:2:"74";i:6;s:2:"75";i:7;s:2:"76";i:8;s:2:"77";}';
$v = unserialize($v);
$v = array_values($v);
print_r($v);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 69
    [1] => 70
    [2] => 71
    [3] => 72
    [4] => 73
    [5] => 74
    [6] => 75
    [7] => 76
    [8] => 77
)
```

`array_values()` isn't even necessary, really.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to delete all numbers between quotation marks, just use

```
$string = preg_replace('/"[0-9]+"/', '""', $string);
```

If you want to delete everything between these, use

```
$string = preg_replace('/"[^"]+"/', '""', $string);
```

To your edited question:

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $string, $matches);
```

$matches will contain an array of arrays containing the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$str = '{i:0;s:2:"69";i:1;s:2:"70";i:2;s:2:"71";i:3;s:2:"72";i:4;s:2:"73";i:5;s:2:"74";i:6;s:2:"75";i:7;s:2:"76";i:8;s:2:"77";}';
$str = preg_replace('#:"[^"]*"#', '', $str);
echo $str . "\n";
```

Comment: It should be noted that this expression removes the preceding colon as well.  So 's:2:"71";' becomes 's:2;'.  This may be what the asker wanted, but it is not what they said.

Comment: @MattH. Good point, however initially I didn't grab `:` and string was left with `:;` and that didn't look right to me so I took little liberty to include `:` in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

**This will be more useful**

```
$data = 'a:9:{i:0;s:2:"69";i:1;s:2:"70";i:2;s:2:"71";i:3;s:2:"72";i:4;s:2:"73";i:5;s:2:"74";i:6;s:2:"75";i:7;s:2:"76";i:8;s:2:"77";}';
$data = unserialize($data);
echo implode(',',$data);
```